# Error is not visible in visual studio, only in postman

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, postman

I'm struggling with this `.GroupBy` statement:

```cs
var groupedTest = taskOccur.GroupBy(x => x.RoundOccurId)
    .Select(x => new FastRoundsForExport
    {
        RoundOccurId = x.Key,
        RoundOccurTasks = x.ToList() //if I comment this line, all works fine
    }).ToList();

var checker = new MeasurementsExportResultsDTO()
{
    AdHocRounds = groupedTest
};

return checker;

// my class

public class FastRoundsForExport
{
   public ICollection<AdHocRoundsForExport> AdHocRounds { get; set; }
}

public class AdHocRoundsForExport
{
   public long RoundOccurId { get; set; }

   public ICollection<TaskOccurrence> RoundOccurTasks { get; set; }
}
```

I sent a request by postman, and I get a 500 error and no readable message, only some strange characters.

I'm returning it with return Ok in the controller, I can see that the data in quick watch is okay, but can't see any error message. My Error debug settings are turn on.

Comment: "some strange characters" don't you have something like gzip compression enabled but without the required header in case of error ?

Comment: And regarding the error in vs, what happens with a try/catch ?

Comment: the problem was , that bug was occurred in another library, in newton json , "Enable just my code " option helps to find it :)